# changing input properties from within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, getelementbyid

On my web page, I have the following:

```
<input type="submit" id="RB$unprocessed[ID]" 
style="background-color:lightsalmon" value="Reject $unprocessed[ID]" />
```

During an Ajax call, I change the color with this:

```
re = document.getElementById("RB" + number);
re.style.background = 'black';
```

This works just fine. I have another set of inputs that are like so

```
<input type="submit" id="btn$itemID" style="font-size:15px; background-color:#FFE6E6; height: 50px; width: 500px" value="$tableCount -  $item (Current $oldCost)" />
```

I try to manipulate the color in the same way as the first,

```
getPriceButton = document.getElementById("btn" + itemID);
getPriceButton.style.background = 'blue';
```

However the button doesn't change colors. Does this have something to do with the `style=` containing more then background color? Do I have to set each property element separately if I want to manipulate them?

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Are you sure of your id ? did you try console.log(getPriceButton) ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have not tried console.log, I will research that. I'm confident the id is right because I change the text in the same manner using the same id and the text changes.

Comment: Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R9zSD/)

Comment: Interesting. This tells me there is a problem somewhere else and not really with the property change.

Comment: It may be a bad ID, the code not called, or the property changed again elsewhere. I'd suggest you to debug.

Comment: What is the best method for debugging directly in firefox?

Comment: Firebug. Or you install Chrome and use [its debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts).

Comment: Got it. Found the problem. During the page generation I was generating html comments and manipulating them with ajax. I removed that feature and now the button changes. Firebug threw a null exception with that particular feature. I'm not exactly sure why it was null tho. Needless to say, I don't need it and I removed it and IT WORKS! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The error was elsewhere, the above code works.